# Collision detection between a Polyline and a Circle

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

So I am rendering a Polyline with the Y-Values of a sin wave with the code below

```
var amplitude = 50;
var dx = (TWO_PI / period) * 10
var yValues = new Array(floor(widthOfWave / xSpacing));
var poly = [];

this.calculate = () => {
    //Increment theta
    theta += 0.02;
    
    //For every x value, calculate the y value with SIN function
    var x = theta;
    for(var i = 0; i < yValues.length; i++) {
        yValues[i] = sin(x) * amplitude;
        x += dx;
    }

this.render = () => {
    this.calculate();
    ellipseMode(CENTER);

    beginShape();
    for(var i = 0; i < yValues.length; i++) {
        var temp = createVector((i * spacing), windowWidth + yValues[i]);
        curveVertex(temp.x, temp.y);
        poly.push(temp);
    }
    endShape();
}
```

Which renders the wave [image]

This is exactly what I want, but the problem I am having is when I try to incorporate p5.collide2d ([Github Link Here](https://github.com/bmoren/p5.collide2D)). I want to have an ellipse, the 'Player' in this case, be able to ride the wave by holding left and right on the keyboard arrows. I haven't gotten to the keyboard interaction, because I am currently stuck on having the Ellipse (a perfect circle) not just falling through the curve at sometimes.

Here is my code for the current collision I am testing with.

```
this.checkCollision = (objX, objY, objSize) => {
    var hit = false;
    var hit = collideCirclePoly(objX, objY, objSize, poly);
    return hit;
}

//Check for the collision
var hit = hill.checkCollision(player1.x, player1.y, player1.size);
if(hit) player1.didCollide();

//Player's didCollide function
this.didCollide = () => {
    newSpeed = this.ySpeed * -0.8;
    this.ySpeed = newSpeed;
}
```

This is how the circle (the "Player") and the wave intereact whenever I try to run it though.
[image]

I can't seem to figure out why the interaction is happening this way. I have tried extending the bounds of the collision, but it just makes it appear very glitchy and it still sometimes just passes through the wave with what appears to be no collision.

I am fairly new to p5.js and processing, so I am most likely missing something very simple. Thanks for your help ahead of time!

Comment: Clearly, in the negative going direction, the algorithm is adjusting the 'y' position so that it no longer collides - and hence speeds up (by about 20% apparently), until it collides again. So where is the code that changes the 'y' value (which is oscillating exponentially)?

Comment: Can you put this in the playground please?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Every time render() gets called, I make the Player (aka the Circle)'s y position increase by ySpeed. e.g : y += ySpeed

Comment: Can you put this in the p5 web editor (playground) please?  http://alpha.editor.p5js.org

Comment: There is just soooo much to wonder about. Like where the `floor()` function comes from and where the `widthOfWave` and `xSpacing` and `temp` and `spacing` variables originated/contain. What exactly does the `this` keyword represent as an execution context. You cannot expect us to help without helping us first. These reasons are why I'm asking you to put this [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) into http://alpha.editor.p5js.org/

Comment: @RandyCasburn Sorry, I forget that when someone else looks at your project they obviously aren't going to understand the workflow by small snippets. Here is the playground http://alpha.editor.p5js.org/ReaganMcF/sketches/HkqVk3eFG

Comment: you've come across a fascinating problem. The collision method you're using isn't going to work for you. It (`collideCirclePoly`) is not designed to work with polylines or sine waves :-). The jitter you see is due to this method using adjacent vectors from your `curveVertex` vertices to create a line between them, and check that line for the collision. So there are many many little vectors created at different vector angles very quickly creating the jitter effect seen. Line 258 here: https://github.com/bmoren/p5.collide2D/blob/master/p5.collide2d.js

Comment: Additionally, this is pretty clear about x-sided polygons (not sinusoidal polylines): https://github.com/bmoren/p5.collide2D#collidecirclepoly. Hope all this helps, sorry for the bad news.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Is there any way to incorporate collision then with sin waves at all? Or is it a lost cause?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be the case with p5.